# На задний двор / В задний двор

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, выбор-варианта

Подскажите, будьте добры, как правильно говорить?

*Окно выходит **на*** (или ***в***) *задний двор*. (Ведь окно выходит во двор.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Окно выходит на задний двор. Окно выходит во двор.***

В общем случае глагол ***выходить*** может сочетаться с предлогами В и НА, выбор делается в каждом конкретном случае (на улицу, на крышу, на море, во двор, в сад).

Учитывается **пространственное значение предлогов** (внутрь предмета или на поверхность предмета), при этом **наличие определения** может влиять на выбор предлога, меняя это пространственное представление.

Сравнить: окно выходит ***в узкий щелевидный двор, на задний двор, во внутренний двор.***

Примеры:

Светомаскировочную черную штору Марина никогда не поднимает ― зачем поднимать, если окно выходит **в узкий щелевидный двор**,  [Ю. В. Трифонов. Исчезновение (1981)

Городской шум не достигает до меня: окно выходит **во внутренний двор.**  [А. С. Серафимович. В номере (1910)]

**Из словаря:**

ВЫХОДИТЬ, нсв. 1. к Выйти. 2. Быть обращённым куда-л., в какую-л. сторону. Окна выходят **в сад**. Эта дверь выходит **на балкон**. Дом выходит фасадом **на площадь**.